# Do some work before element rendered

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add some css styles (`display: none`) before an element is rendered.

The problem is that I'm trying to do it in a jQuery plugin and I can't initialize the plugin in the header.

I'm not sure what is possible in my case

Plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
           if (options.collapsed_mode) {
              $('#menu').hide();
           }
        }
    };

    $.fn.dropright = function (method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' not found');
        }
        return true;
    };
});
```

Page:

```
<?php include 'templates/header.php'; ?>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
       Hello, world ;)
    </div>
</div>
<?php include 'templates/fooer.php'; ?>
```

---

### Update

I can't add to the css file `display: none` because, in different pages, I need different values for `display`. For example, where the plugin is included, I need `display: none`, but for any another, the element should not be hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `.hide()` on the element until it's been rendered onto the page.  JavaScript isn't the right tool for the job here.

Instead, add `display: none` to the element's CSS (and make sure the CSS file is loaded before the element).  You've noted that this should only be on certain pages.  Cool.  Only load this CSS on those pages.

```
#menu {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Accept your answer. Now, i use different templates for different page. I not see another way for solve this problem. Thank you